# Mesh doesn't follow the armature after Armature Deform with Automatic Weights

Tags: animation, mesh, armature

I've been learning blender for a couple of days now and I have a problem that I couldn't solve. I'm following this tutorial btw: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkiWBSSuxLw&ab_channel=Imphenzia. I selected the body and then shift selected the armature then CTRL + P and "Armature Deform with Automatic Weights" as he did in the video, but when I move the armature, the mesh doesn't follow it. It stands still. Here are some screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: https://pasteall.org/blend/019d7eadd4014632a3fd219e67f6f634 -> File

Comment: hello, please share your file (upload and share the URL): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: added the link to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parentage actually failed. What you need to do is:

- Delete all the vertex groups (in the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups* list, down arrow button on the right > *Delete All Groups*)
- Some normals are inverted, select your object and in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> in order to recalculate the normals.
- You have overlapping vertices, select your object and in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*

Parent again, it should work

Comment: it works. Thanks man.